# Android Development SQLite vs. Hashtable

Tags: java, android, sqlite, hashtable

So I'm following a tutorial on how to create a simple Android app that stores a bunch of random quotes. I've noticed that they used a SQLite database and many other Android tutorials uses SQLite to store things. I'm not  very used to SQLite. Can I achieve the same result just by storing the quotes in a hashtable?

What are the differences between a SQLite database and a hashtable in terms of performance?

Comment: hashtable is volatile memory, while sqlite is persistence storage medium.

Comment: If you store your data in HashTable then Your data will be loss when application closed, If you want to make it to permanent use SQLite database..

Comment: For performance, HashTable is faster (Because its available in Primary Memory) then SQLite but not persist.

Answer (score 3):

> What are the differences between a SQLite database and a hashtable in terms of performance?

An (in-memory) hash table is (you probably should use `HashMap`) is going to be faster.  However, it does not address the problem of making your quotes "persist" when your app has shut down.

SQLite is a database, and the main point of a database is that the data persists.

(There are a whole bunch of other benefits in using a database of some kind.  One that is potentially relevant to you is that you can store more stuff in a typical database than you can hold in memory.  The database stores stuff on your device's hard drive / SSD / whatever which has far more capacity than main memory.)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/25023.aspx

I suggest SQLite because u can access the database very easily and it is easy to understand and view the database tables also very easy through DDMS plugin for eclipse The above link helps you in DDMS

Answer (score 0):

It's up to your intention. If you want to store data such as app preference, user score.. use SQLite. These data will be available for the next launch of application. Hashtable is in memory, of course it is faster than SQLite, all information stored in Hashtable will be lost when the app is deactived or terminated.